# Execute command on shell command output

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a command that runs forever and periodically output stuff until it gets killed by something else (similar to `tail -f`), and I want to make it so that whenever there's new output another command gets executed.

Caveats:

- I can't use Bash
- That command obviously isn't `tail`, it just behaves in a similar manner
- That command's output doesn't always come in lines, and I do not intend to execute that other command for each line of the output
- Polling is not an acceptable solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using `dd` to trigger a shell command whenever something is read from stdin, whether terminated by newline or not:

```
{
   printf not-nl-terminated
   sleep 1
   printf '%s\n' nl-terminated
   sleep 1
   echo
   sleep 1
   printf 'binary\0data'
} | 
while : ; do
   input=$(dd bs=1M count=1 2>/dev/null | tr '\n\0' __)
   [ "$input" ] || break
   printf 'input of size %d\n' "${#input}" 
done
```

will give

```
input of size 17
input of size 14
input of size 1
input of size 11
```

This snippet from the [standard spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) may help understand `dd`'s behavior when `bs=` is used explicily:

> If the `bs=` expr operand is
>        specified and no conversions other than `sync`, `noerror`, or `notrunc`
>        are requested, the data returned from each input block shall be
>        written as a separate output block; if the read returns **less than a
>        full block** and the `sync` conversion is not specified, the resulting
>        output block shall be the same size as the input block. If the `bs=`
>        expr operand is not specified, or a conversion other than `sync`,
>        `noerror`, or `notrunc` is requested, the input shall be processed and
>        collected into full-sized output blocks until the end of the input
>        is reached.

Comment: yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: in any case the command line substitution at `input=$(dd bs=1G count=1 2>/dev/null)` is going to cause the trailing newline to be eaten.

Comment: Yes, that's why it says "13 bytes". If needed, that could be worked around with `input=$(...; printf x); input=${input%x}`